# Update PHP <input> field from JavaScript with a GMaps Marker position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I've managed to add markers to a Google Map on click, but now I need to update an `<input>` field inside a form each time a new marker is placed. So, when a new marker is placed, the input in question is updated with the latitude and longitude of the marker.

I'm using Google Maps Javascript API v3.

Here's my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.47860556892209,-3.328857421875),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        //NEITHER OF THESE 2 OPTIONS WORK
        cambiarMarker(event.latLng);
        //document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
        //document.getElementById("lng").value = levent.latLng.lng();
        document.forms['insertData'].lati.value = location.lat();
        document.forms['insertData'].long.value = location.lng();   
    });

    var markerActual;

    function cambiarMarker(location) {
        //CREATES AND PUT THE NEW MARKER
    }

    downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml2.php", function(data) {
        //GETS INFO FROM AN XML THAT IS CREATED FROM THE DATABASE WITH PHP 
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
        //BINDS INFORMATION WINDOW WITH THE XML INFO
    }


    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        //GET THE XML FILE
    }

    function parseXml(str) {
        //PARSES FROM THE XML
    }

    function doNothing() {}
</script>
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<body onload="load()">
    Aqui debería salir algo
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
    <form name="insertData" action="insertar_datos.php" method="post">
        Nombre: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        Dirección: <input type="text" name="address"><br>
        Latitud: <input type="text" name="lati" id="lat"><br> <!--HERE'S INPUT1-LATITUDE-->
        Longitud: <input type="text" name="long" id="lng"><br> <!--HERE'S INPUT2-LONG-->
        Teléfono de contacto: <input type="text" name="telefono"><br>
        Comentario: <textarea name="comentario"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle you could also handle `change` event on the input field and set the coordinates of the marker. This is what I'm doing in my application. And also I handle the `drag` event of a marker and change the coordinates during dragging. In this case handle both `drag` and `dragend` events of a marker! The `dragend` you MUST handle, the `drag` not so but it is cool to let the coordinates change as you drag the marker :)

The change event of input field can be handled e.g. this way (using jquery, supposing markup like `<input id="coords"...`):

```
$('input#coords').change(function () {
    // do the job here: 
    // - convert field coordinates to latLng
    //   for reading the field value use $('input#coords').val()
    // - set the marker position to the new one
});
```

Comment: I'm a true newbie in JS and PHP. Can you please lead me in how to handle the change event? I might implement the change on drag, but first I want to make the simple one work :P

Comment: @danirolo7, I updated my post to show how to handle the event using jquery.